# Element not loading CSS Class

Tags: css, class, element, display

and on advance thank you for your time.

I have to overlook 12 websites, and I give a quick check on them to make sure that the Wordpress, Theme Folder, or Browser updates don't make them not work all the sudden. Now, it has been over 2 months, and when I left everything. Well, everything was working. No updates since. Plus, here is another catch. I have to versions of it. English and Spanish. All the same code, and on the same editor, same everything except the language. Well, everything looks good. I have spent all day of my job looking on how to resolve the issue, and I don't seem to see anything wrong with it. So, I was wondering if could someone give a quick look, and give some feedback. 'Cause this is really killing me. I give the links, so you can see it yourselves what the issue is, and image to the editor, so you can see that Things there are also fine.

This is my Problem. The header is not displaying the way it supposed to. Some CSS Classes are not being loaded, while just about everything else is. All the Headers CSS Class is found only in one file, and it is reading the file, just the certain Class are being ignored. Here is the Link of the page with the issue. [Spanish Link](http://spanish.clinicamedicafamiliardrrios.com) and here is the [English Link](http://clinicamedicafamiliardrrios.com) with no issue having the same code, and now for the image of the Spanish homepage in [Editor Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHcbD.png). Thank you once again.

note:(*Spinsh link is with the issue, and the image of the editor is of the Spanish Link as well*)...

Comment: Sorry we need code in the question so we can work with that. Links to sites that you are actively working on can change moment to moment and will be useless once the problem is resolved. By reducing the problem to a [MCVE] you will make it easier to determine exactly where the problem is. Use the broswer dev tools (F12) to inspect your problem elements to see what styles are being applied and what are being over written. Use this as a basis for you debugging ad reducing the scope of the problem

Comment: Agreeing with Jon P -- it might be worth reviewing [ask], as well formed questions are the best way to get high quality answers.  Also, I am generally reluctant to click out to some random third party site-- I'm sure many others are as well.  It might be better to recreate your issue in a code snippet in your question or in a known code sharing tool like codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you @Jon P and Alexander Nied for your time. Well, I would love to give a minimal code, and some coding on codepen for the problem, but the header were I am having the issue has to many classes, and elements, that no matter how much minimal coding I provide, or even if I put it on codepen, is still going to be really long. At this time we are not going to edit anything on live until we are able to reproduce the same error internally, which we haven't had luck yet.

Comment: Thank you Jon P and @AlexanderNied, I don't blame you for not wanting to click on third part sites. lol Same here. Well, I tried the issue in chrome, firefox with original icon, and the IE error turns out the same problem in different browsers, *But* yesterday I downloaded the Firefox for developers which is a blue icon, and it had the same problem, *and* this morning I logged in and went to visit the site again, and it is display the header as it should. In other words it's working on this Firefox browser. I clean the cache on the other browsers to see if they also went normal, and they are.

Comment: We never were able to reproduce the error, nor did we ever edit anything live during all this time. Some how the browsers were causing the problem. To be honest we will never know.